# Shellscript Looping Through All Files and adjusting symlink

Tags: macos, bash, loops, symlink

I was trying to get [libetpan](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan) up and running on iOS, however there seemed to be something wrong with their setup shell script (problem explained in more [detail](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan/issues/48#issuecomment-11030688) here).. but basically I got a  folder with a long list of symlinks pointing to nowhere ie

```
mhdriver_types.h -> ../../src/driver/implementation/mh/mhdriver_types.h
```

when in fact it should be

```
mhdriver_types.h -> ../../../src/driver/implementation/mh/mhdriver_types.h
```

I want to write a shell script that loops through all the symlinks, deleting each, then recreating a symlink for it to the same former destination only one subdirectory deeper.. basically doing what i did in the example to all the files..

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inspired by anishsane's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743979/766570) i got this code that works:

```
for name in $(find . -type l); do
    tgt=`readlink "$name"`
    ln -sf ../$tgt
done
```

Comment: I generally avoid using `for filename in $(command)`. Because in worst case, when filenames contain spaces, it fails. `while read` is more stable solution. (Personally, I also used `for var in` syntax earlier. But now moved to `while read` syntax. :D)

Comment: interesting.. well then the only lose end in this discussion is: why didn't your code work with me? the only difference is while loop vs for loop.. lemme do some more digging and see what comes up :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find $DIR_PATH -type l | while read x; do tgt=`readlink "$x"`; ln -sf ../$tgt $x; done
```

Comment: i get 
find: illegal option -- t
find: illegal option -- y
find: illegal option -- p
find: illegal option -- e
find: l: No such file or directory

Comment: Oh, I did not see iOS in description... The find command may have different options on iOS.

Comment: i'm implementing this in the mac osx shell.. not in iOS.. but anyways lemme try different variations of your command

Comment: Check for `find` manual; on how to get list of only symlinks.

Comment: i just [got](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13744728/766570) the correct answer.. but i'll +1 yours, since I was inspired by it.. and since you seem like a good guy :)

Comment: This is odd. `find . -type l` worked in your case, but gave error `illegal option` in the code I gave? I believe you had replaced $DIR_PATH with your directory.